# iteration counter for GCD

Tags: python, iteration

I have the following code for calulating the GCD of two numbers:

```
def gcd(m, n):
   r = m % n
   while r != 0:
      m = n
      n = r
      r = m % n
   return n

print ("\n", "gcd (10, 35) = ", gcd(10, 35))

print ("\n", "gcd (735, 175) = ", gcd(735, 175))

print ("\n", "gcd (735, 350) = ", gcd(735, 350))
```

I would like to count the number of iterations that the algorithm has to go through before finding the GCD. I am having trouble making a for loop to determine the number of iterations.

Comment: just add counter and return it with n

Comment: *"I would like to count the number of iterations"* - So do that?

Comment: set `counter=0` outside the definition and increment it each time the code in the `while` loop is executed

Comment: Any reason you're reinventing `fractions.gcd` (or in modern Python, the faster builtin `math.gcd`)?

Comment: ... how on earth were you able to write this function but not figure out how to count the iterations? ... oh wait i know ... make sure you study hard... the assignments are real easy next to the tests (and you cant ask SO to do your tests for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def gcd(m, n):
   r = m % n
   counter = 0
   while r != 0:
      m = n
      n = r
      r = m % n
      counter += 1
   return n, counter
```